# Перенос текста в ячейке TableView

Tags: java, javafx

Как сделать чтобы в ячейке таблицы текст переносился на следующую строчку, чтобы высота ячейки увеличивалась.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class WrapTextTableCell<S> extends TableCell<S, String> {

    private Text text;

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if ( text != null ) {
            text.textProperty().unbind();
        }
        if ( empty || item == null ) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if ( text == null ) {
                text = new Text();
                text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(getTableColumn().widthProperty());
            }
            text.textProperty().bind(itemProperty());
            setGraphic(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо использовать метода `setWarpText` на ячейке.

Попробуйте так

```
column.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.setWarpText(true));
```

это можно сделать в методе `initialize` контроллера.

Comment: Не понимаю как из этого обратиться к ячейке

Comment: @Youlfey cell -> cell.setWarpText(true) это и есть обращение к ячейке

Comment: у меня это не компилируется, метод у cell не находит

Comment: Код из данного ответа нерабочий.