# JavaFX. Как сделать перенос строки в ячейке TreeTableView?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Интересует вопрос связанный с переносом текста на новую строку при достижении границ ячейки в TreeTableView. Нашел похожий вопрос: [Перенос текста в ячейке TableView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747869/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B5-tableview).
Но не смог интегрировать его в свой код, не понимаю, что нужно отправлять в метод класса

Comment: @insolor, Спасибо! Код работает именно в таком виде `column.setCellFactory(param -> new WrapTextTableCell<>())`. Где _param_, по сути любое наименование. Можете оформить как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для колонки, где нужен перенос строки, указываете фабрику ячеек через метод `setCellFactory`, будет что-то вроде `column.setCellFactory(param -> new WrapTextTableCell<>())`, код для класса `WrapTextTableCell` берете из ответа по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/749520/1365), только базовый класс `TableCell` меняете на `TreeTableCell` (т.к. у вас `TreeTableView` а не `TableView`):

```
public class WrapTextTableCell<S> extends TreeTableCell<S, String> {

    private Text text;

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if ( text != null ) {
            text.textProperty().unbind();
        }
        if ( empty || item == null ) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if ( text == null ) {
                text = new Text();
                text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(getTableColumn().widthProperty());
            }
            text.textProperty().bind(itemProperty());
            setGraphic(text);
        }
    }
}
```